# WPF Focus on the ListBox Item with control Template

Tags: wpf, mvvm, wpf-controls

I have a Listbox with a Item Template as Text box  and button (Add) . whenever the Button is clicked one more item(Textbox) is added. Once the Button is clicked i want to give the focus to the first text box or the one which is added recently. How can i do it in WPF.If possible from MVVM end with testable way

Comment: Can you post the relevant xaml code here?? It will be easy to figure out with your code..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm completly agreed with Daniel's answer, but let me clarify this idea with some code.

At first let's define attached behaviour which reacts on "true"-values and set focus for its owner.

```
public static class FocusBehaviour
{
    public static bool GetForceFocus(DependencyObject d)
    {
        return (bool)d.GetValue(FocusBehaviour.ForceFocusProperty);
    }

    public static void SetForceFocus(DependencyObject d, bool val)
    {
        d.SetValue(FocusBehaviour.ForceFocusProperty, val);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ForceFocusProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ForceFocus", 
            typeof(bool), 
            typeof(FocusBehaviour), 
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, 
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.None, 
                (d, e) => 
                    {
                        if((bool)e.NewValue)
                        {
                            if (d is UIElement)
                            {
                                ((UIElement)d).Focus();
                            }
                        }
                    }));
}
```

Then add this behaviour to our TextBox:

```
<DataTemplate>
     <TextBox self:FocusBehaviour.ForceFocus="{Binding IsFocused}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

Of course you should add IsFocused property to your item class:

```
public class Item : ObservableObject
{
    //...
    private bool _isFocused = true;
    public bool IsFocused
    {
        get
        {
            return this._isFocused;
        }
        set
        {
            this._isFocused = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("IsFocused");
        }
    }
}
```

And somewhere in your code you should manipulate with IsFocused property for your items. 
For example, when you add new item, you should reset IsFocused for all items, except newbie. When you initialize collection, you should set IsFocused only for the first item.

Comment: This really helped me, but I had to add a while loop to walk up the visual tree using `VisualTreeHelper` to find the first parent that has `Focusable == true`

Answer (score 2):

I would do it like this:

1. In your VM, have a `ObservableCollection` with the items.
2. In your VM, have a property `SelectedItem`.
3. In your VM, have a command `AddItem`.
4. Wire the button to the command `AddItem`.
5. Bind the `SelectedItem` of your `ComboBox` to the `SelectedItem` of your VM.
6. In the `AddItem` command, add the item to the `ObservableCollection` and assign it to the `SelectedItem` of your VM.
7. In your DataTemplate, make sure the TextBox gets the focus when the item is selected.

To achieve the last point, you could create an attached property that returns `IsFocused` in the getter and calls `Focus` in the setter. You then could then attach this property to the textbox and bind it to an `IsFocused` property in your item.